# The range projection of equivalent elements in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $a,b\in M$. Suppose $a\geq b$ and $a$ is equivalent to $c\in M$.

Then there exists $d\in M$ such that $d$ is equivalent to $b$ and $c\geq d$.

Since $a$ is equivalent to $c$, there exists a partial isometry $u\in M$ such that $a=u^*u,c=uu^*$. So we have $uau^*\geq ubu^*$, and thus $c=uu^*\geq ubu^*$. If we let $d：=ubu^*$, how to check that $d$ is equivalent to $b$? If the above proof is not correct, how to find $d$ such that $d$ is equivalent to $b$ and $c\geq d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you don't mention is that $a,b,c,d$ are projections.

You have $d=ubu^*=(bu^*)^*bu^*$. So $d$ is equivalent to
$$
bu^*ub=bab=b^2=b.
$$